# Whats is the replacement for spec_files in RSpec::Core::RakeTask ? Does pattern accept array of files?

Tags: rspec, rake

I was previously using the older version : Spec::Rake::SpecTask.

I notice now spec_files is deprecated. What is the replacement for this?

Does pattern accept an array of files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

has the pattern accept an array of files as this example bellow:

```
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc 'Default: run specs.'
task :default => :spec

desc "Run specs"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.pattern = ['spec/**/*_spec.rb', 'spec/**/**/*_spec.rb']
end
```